# CMake illogic path parsing?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to include [this](https://github.com/commschamp/cc.ublox.commsdsl) project into my cmake code base.
I cloned the repo to my include/ dir and added this line to my CMakeLists.txtx:

```
add_subdirectory(${DIVISIBLE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/cc.ublox.commsdsl)
include_directories(${DIVISIBLE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${DIVISIBLE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But when I try to rebuild my project it says that it can't find the defined scheme files:

```
[WARNING]: failed to load external entity "/Users/pete/Documents/projekte/simple-dgps/dsl/main.xml"
```

If I add the project prefix(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR) to the scheme files path the path appears twice.

```
ERROR: Failed to parse/Users/pete/Documents/projekte/simple-dgps/Users/pete/Documents/projekte/simple-dgps/include/cc.ublox.commsdsl/dsl/main.xml
```

And if I fill the missing part between simple-dgps and dsl (which would be `include/cc.ublox.commsdsl`) I get this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `include/cc.ublox.commsdsl/include/cc.ublox.commsdsl/dsl/main.xml', needed by `output.tmp'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [include/cc.ublox.commsdsl/CMakeFiles/cc.ublox.commsdsl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Assuming that the first error relates to a wrong file location, what does the second mean then(although it clearly has the wrong path because it exists twice)

Comment: This `CMakeLists.txt` project is written to be run as standalone, not to be included via `add_subdirectory`.  You can tell because it uses `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` all over the place which is not where you put the project, this variable points to your project.  This can be fixed by using something like `<PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR` instead because a new project is defined.  Its not going to be straight forward, you have to modify the cc.ublox.commsdsl `CMakeLists.txt`.  Could be easier to treat it as an external project instead.

Comment: I've done that but the path is still put in twice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem for the double path problem.
I added the project as subdir from my main project by adding this line:

```
add_subdirectory(${DIVISIBLE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/cc.ublox.commsdsl)
```

The problem is that DIVISIBLE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR is a absolute path and thus is added to the cmake source dir of the subdir.
This can be fixed by using:

```
add_subdirectory(include/cc.ublox.commsdsl)
```

Comment: Please show which variable `CMake` sets incorrectly when using an absolute path with `add_subdirectory()`.  Simple testing shows that `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` all show the correct absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely seems to be with defining the project path for `cc.ublox.commsdsl` vs the project path for your project.

> If I add the project prefix(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR) to the scheme files path the path appears twice.

Can you share what you added? `/Users/pete/Documents/projekte/simple-dgps/include/cc.ublox.commsdsl/dsl/main.xml` looks right for the `cc.ublox.commsdsl` path - but it seems you may have added the path such that it gets duplicated. Hard to tell what's wrong without looking at what you added.

Comment: I changed it to this: `set (schema_files
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dsl/main.xml`

Comment: Ah, so maybe `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is where the duplication lies. Where is `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` defined?

Comment: `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is `The path to the top level of the source tree.` and is defined by `CMake` when you run `CMake` at the command line.

Comment: And why is it put into my path twice then? (thx for rply)

Comment: Because of the edits you made; but its hard to pinpoint because you haven't shown us exactly what you changed.